# Cannot read Image from ImageReader using CircularByteBuffer in java

Tags: java, image, stream, buffer

I have the following code :

```
List<PDXObjectImage> list = new ArrayList<PDXObjectImage>(someValues);
CircularByteBuffer cbb = new CircularByteBuffer(CircularByteBuffer.INFINITE_SIZE);

for(int k=0;k<list.size();k++)
{
    list.get(k).write2OutputStream(cbb.getOutputStream());
    ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(cbb.getInputStream());
    Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
    if (iter.hasNext()) {
        ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) iter.next();
        reader.addIIOReadProgressListener(new IIOReadProgressListener(){...});
        reader.setInput(iis, true, true);

        System.out.println("Still okay");
        BufferedImage img = reader.read(0, null);
        System.out.println("Not okay");

        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
        model.addRow(new Object[]{imageIcon});
    }
}
```

The program always display "Still okay", but never "Not okay".

The `IIOReadProgressListener` shows that the reader reads up to 82.4% of the image before blocking.

Before I start using `CircularByteBuffer`, I was using a serie of `ByteArrayOutputStream`, `ByteArrayInputStream`, `OutputStream`, and `InputStream`, but I had to change because of an `OutOfMemoryError : Java Heap Space`.

If someone knows what is happening, I would really appreciate some help,

Thank you

EDIT:

The same thing happens using the following code:

```
List<PDXObjectImage> list = new ArrayList<PDXObjectImage>(someValues);

for(int k=0;k<list.size();k++)
{
    PipedOutputStream convertPipe = new PipedOutputStream();
    PipedInputStream dataPipe = new PipedInputStream(convertPipe,1000000);
    img.write2OutputStream(convertPipe);
    ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(dataPipe);
    Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
    if (iter.hasNext()) {
        ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) iter.next();
        reader.addIIOReadProgressListener(new IIOReadProgressListener(){...});
        reader.setInput(iis, true, true);

        System.out.println("Still okay");
        BufferedImage img = reader.read(0, null);
        System.out.println("Not okay");

        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
        model.addRow(new Object[]{imageIcon});
    }
}
```

Comment: `CycledByteBuffer`/`CircularByteBuffer`?? What is it?

Comment: I am sorry at one point for the use of `CycledByteBuffer`, I actually ment `CircularByteBuffer`

Comment: Don't you need a second thread to push data into the buffer for this to work? As the "current" thread will be stuck waiting for data from the buffer...